# how to put quotation marks for string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cat_unique = ['greetings',
 'BB_Device_has_physical_damage',
 'Cracked_Shatterd_screen_Yes',
 'Cracked_Shatterd_screen_No',
 'Broken_split_or_deformed_case_Yes',
 'Broken_split_or_deformed_case_No',
 'Is_it_bent_batter_prongs_Yes',
 'Is_it_bent_battery_prongs_No',
 'Laser_window_cracked_Missing_Yes',
 'Laser_window_cracked_Missing_No',
 'Screen_not_respoding_Yes',
 'Screen_not_respoding_No',
 'it_Missed_Trigger_Buttons_Yes',
 'Missed_Trigger_Buttons_No']
```

I want to print with quotation marks `cat_unique[0]` as `"greetings"`? How can i do this?

Comment: I don't know about PHYTON 3.X, but in python, the quotes are irrelevant here. If you want to _display_ them with quotes, however, you can use `json.dumps(cat_unique)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you post your attempts as your question currently sounds like you're asking for code which is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to print ":

```
print('"'+ cat_unique[0] + '"') # using single quotes
print("\"" + cat_unique[0] + "\"") # escaping the quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem in cat_unique: print ('{0}{1}{2}'.format('"', elem, '"'))
```

You can print your list element by using this code.

Comment: If you will use '"{}"'.format(elem) then the desired output won't come up.

Comment: Works for me and is marked as accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757133/how-to-print-variable-inside-quotation-marks

Comment: yeah you are right. I didn't see your double quotes around curly braces. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can just simply add the double quotes to the string

```
>>> cat_unique = ['"greetings"']
>>> print(cat_unique[0])
"greetings"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(len(cat_unique)):
    cat_unique[i]='"'+cat_unique[i]+'"'

print cat_unique
```

it will add double quote to each element in list

Comment: '"'+cat_unique[4]+'"' giving '"Broken_split_or_deformed_case_Yes"'