# Getting strings from looping over a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop over `tasks` list:

```
tasks = [
         'NR-AR', 'NR-AR-LBD', 'NR-AhR', 'NR-Aromatase', 'NR-ER', 'NR-ER-LBD',
         'NR-PPAR-gamma', 'SR-ARE', 'SR-ATAD5', 'SR-HSE', 'SR-MMP', 'SR-p53'
        ]
```

The output I get with:

```
for task in range(len(tasks)):
    print(tasks[task])
```

is:

```
NR-AR
NR-AR-LBD
NR-AhR
NR-Aromatase
NR-ER
NR-ER-LBD
NR-PPAR-gamma
SR-ARE
SR-ATAD5
SR-HSE
SR-MMP
SR-p53
```

What I was not able to do is getting the same output but with `"..."` for each task.

For example: `"SR-p53"` instead of `SR-p53`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print list elements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097264/how-to-print-list-elements-in-one-line)

Comment: Correct dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757133/how-to-print-variable-inside-quotation-marks ; OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/printing-double-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: `for task in tasks: print(f'"{task}"')`

Comment: This is actually an X-Y problem. OP states that they want to assign the result to a variable to use it as string in one of the answer's comments. `tasks[task]` is already a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by either of the ways:

1. Using format method of string

   ```
    print('"{}"'.format(tasks[task]))
   ```
2. Formatting string with 'f':

   ```
    print(f'"{tasks[task]}"')
   ```
3. Using modulus operator for formatting:

   ```
    print('"%s"' % tasks[task])
   ```
4. Using string concatenation:

   ```
    print('"' + tasks[task] + '"')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'f' in print method to format and then include double quotes.

**See the code below:**

```
tasks = [
      'NR-AR', 'NR-AR-LBD', 'NR-AhR', 'NR-Aromatase', 'NR-ER', 'NR-ER-LBD',
      'NR-PPAR-gamma', 'SR-ARE', 'SR-ATAD5', 'SR-HSE', 'SR-MMP', 'SR-p53'
    ]

for task in range(len(tasks)):
    print(f'"{tasks[task]}"')
```

Comment: and can I use this to assign "SR-p53" as a string to a variable and not for print only ??

Comment: @TrikiSadok Please see the duplicate I provided (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/printing-double-quotes-around-a-variable) It solves this question as well

Comment: @Asocia I believe he meant to save it with the quotes as a string variable which can be done by `s = '"SR-p53"'`

Comment: If you want to assign "SR-p53" you can put it in single quotes like this `string = ' "SR-p53" '`. If you print the variable string `print(string)` the output will be "SR-p53".